# The adverb "reasonably" can be about the level of language knowledge?

Tags: word-in-context

The adverb "**reasonably**" can be about the level of language knowledge?

For example, can I say *"He speaks English reasonably"*, meaning he speaks in a level he can speak and understand the most of the things (but not he doesn't speak fluently).

Comment: Yes, it certainly can. Would it be misunderstood? Possibly.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use another adverb after "reasonably," for example: "He speaks English reasonably well." It's like you don't say: "He speaks English pretty." but "He speaks English pretty well."

The word "reasonably" alone sounds like "logically." You can use "[reasonably](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/reasonably)" alone when saying: "He speaks reasonably," which means that what he says makes sense.

Comment: Thank you +^1. So, if I'd like to say the the he speaks in a way that he can be understood somehow (between a beginner and a intermediate one) but of course not pretty well as you said, what adverb is appropriate for this purpose?

Comment: "He speaks well enough to be understood," for example.

Comment: But you *could* say *pretty*, although you normally wouldn't use it over *prettily*. It would be interpreted similarly to *beautifully*, although to a somewhat lesser degree. Just because it's being used as a flat adjective doesn't mean it's wrong or misunderstood.